# How do I insert things from a lineedit into MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt

I'm making a form which allows me to add questions to a database. I've written code but when I try it I get this error *('AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GetTable')*

The error lies with this part of my code `'t = self.dbu.GetTable()'`

```
@QtCore.pyqtSignature("on_add_btn_clicked()")
def Add_btn(self):
    Question = self.Question_lineEdit.text()#Grabs the text from all line edit fields
    Answer = self.Answer_lineEdit.text()
    IsmultiChoice = self.IsMultiChoice_lineEdit.text()
    if not Question:
        QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning', 'Username Missing')
    else:
        t = self.dbu.GetTable()
        print (t)
        for col in t:
            if Question == col[1]:
                QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Warning', 'Question Taken. :(')#Checks the database and warns if the database does exist                               
        else:
            self.dbu.AddEntryToTable (Question, Answer, isMultiChoice)
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Success', 'User Added Successfully!')#If everythings is okay it adds the user 
            self.close()
```

Here is my database code:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from datetime import datetime



class DatabaseUtility: 
    def __init__(self, database, Tablename,):
        self.db = database
        self.Tablename = Tablename




        self.cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root',
                                    password = '',
                                    host = 'localhost')


        self.cursor = self.cnx.cursor()

    def ConnectToDatabase(self):
        try:
            self.cnx.database = self.db 
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            if err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
                self.CreateDatabase()
                self.cnx.database = self.db
            else:
                print(err.msg)

    def CreateDatabase(self):
        try:
            self.RunCommand("CREATE DATABASE %s DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8';" %self.db)
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print("Failed creating database: {}".format(err))



    def GetTable(self):
        self.Tablename()
        return self.RunCommand("SELECT * FROM %s;" % self.Tablename)











    def GetColumns(self):
        return self.RunCommand("SHOW COLUMNS FROM %s;" % self.Tablename)




    def RunCommand(self, cmd):
        print ("RUNNING COMMAND: " + cmd)
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(cmd)
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print ('ERROR MESSAGE: ' + str(err.msg))
            print ('WITH ' + cmd)
        try:
            msg = self.cursor.fetchall()
        except:
            msg = self.cursor.fetchone()
        return msg

    def AddEntryToTable(self, Question, Answer,IsMultiChoice):
        cmd = " INSERT INTO " + self.Tablename + " (Question, Answer, IsMultiChoice)"
        cmd += " VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s');" % (Question, Answer, IsMultiChoice)
        self.RunCommand(cmd)


    def __del__(self):#Deconstructer class
        self.cnx.commit()
        self.cursor.close()
        self.cnx.close()

















if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = 'UsernamePassword_DB'
    Tablename = 'questiontable'



    dbu = DatabaseUtility(db, Tablename)
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I correct it?

Comment: Where is `dbu` defined on the class `Add_btn` is defined in? In other words, can you include the code where `dbu` is first created, which I expect might be in the class's `__init__()` method?

Answer (score 1):

I'd need to see some additional code to be sure (see my comment). But for now my guess is it has to do with how you first instantiate or reference the `dbu` variable/attribute. If all you did is *import* it from another file, because `dbu` is created in that file's `main()` (in the snippet you provided), that might be the issue. For example, this is ***incorrect***:

```
from whatever import dbu  # wrong
from whatever.main import dbu  # Also wrong. In fact I don't think this would even work
```

Instead, import `DatabaseUtility` directly into the script, *then* instantiate `dbu` like :

```
from whatever import Database Utility
class SomeClass(object):
...
def startDB(self, db, Tablename):
  self.dbu = DatabaseUtility(db, Tablename)
```

The reason I guess this is because the error message says **module** has no attribute, instead of mentioning the actual class. Here's an example of the error I would *expect* to see:

```
In [31]: class MyClass(object):
    one = 1
   ....:     
In [32]: myc = MyClass()
In [33]: myc.one
Out[33]: 1
In [34]: myc.two
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-4bae87671838> in <module>()
----> 1 myc.two

AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'two'
```

Notice how it says *MyClass* is the problem, not "module".

Potentially unrelated, you might want to remove `self.Tablename()` from `DatabaseUtility.GetTable()`. The way you have your class defined, `Table` is an *attribute* to the `DatabaseUtility` class, but by including the parentheses you're trying to call it as if it were a *method* (like `GetTable` is).